# Cannot add org.eclipse.e4.rcp feature

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I'm following the [Eclipse RCP tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html) by Lars Vogel, and am on section 5.7 (*Enter the feature as content into the product*).

I opened the `todo.product` product file and changed the product configuration file to use features.  I then selected the Contents tab, but cannot add the following features:

- org.eclipse.e4.rcp
- org.eclipse.emf.ecore
- org.eclipse.emf.common

The following screenshot shows the available features:

[image]

I'm developing on a Mac with Eclipse 2020-06, and here's a screenshot of my target platform.

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Looks like your target platform contents are wrong.

Comment: The target platform is set to Running Platform (Active), and it shows a location of eclipse/java-2020-06/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/.  Anything else I should check?

Comment: The running platform should always contain the features you want plus a lot more. Edit the target platform definition and make sure all the features you want are selected (Content tab, Manage using Features option).

Comment: @greg-449 I just edited my original post with a screenshot of the target platform.  Should there be an org.eclipse.e4.rcp feature?  I installed Eclipse for Java, and not Eclipse EE.  Would that make a difference?

Comment: The RCP and RAP developers install would be the correct one. I guess some of the others may leave out org.eclipse.e4.rcp. This is why using a separate target platform rather than just the Running Platform is recommended. A target platform based on `http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.16` for example will have all features available.

Comment: OK, installing Eclipse IDE for RCP and RAP Developers did the trick.  Thank you very much @greg-449!!!

Answer (score 0):

Installing Eclipse IDE for RCP and RAP Developers did the trick.